# How to only keep required files when createing a dist packageget

Tags: php, composer-php

When using composer to get dependencies a huge amount of unnecessary files are download such as documentations, test units, etc. These make the built file large. How to only include production files from composer folder?

Comment: @PaulCrovella Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the most package developer don't exploit `.gitattributes` files and using or not using `--prefer-dist` is the same for them. I come up with the following gulp task: https://gist.github.com/salarmehr/b62703afb6617f4cacac

Answer (score -1):

This isn't as easy as it looks at first glance.

Composer itself isn't the right place to fiddle with project's published code. So the next stop is `.gitattributes`.

Symfony tried to do this, and their experience made them [revert this decision](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/6605). Composer had information about using `.gitattributes` in the documentation, but [removed it](https://github.com/composer/composer/commit/b34220edc8ed738bce3f682248622976543d6ec4).

In essence, removing some part of a package from a distinct distribution path is likely to cause more problems than it solves. From my perspective, the CLI switch `--prefer-dist` and `--prefer-source` is a selector of either having to clone a huge repository that takes ages or download a ZIP with that exact version - but the results should be equal, i.e. I should not be forced to `--prefer-source` for ALL my dependencies just because one single package that decided to "optimize for deployment" decided to remove documentation and tests from their ZIP.

Yes, during development I usually look at their code and tests to help me understand what's going on - or what SHOULD go on, and isn't.

Conclusion: Composer is NOT a deployment tool. If you care about the size of your application, it is your task to remove everything you don't need or want, and probably optimize other things as well (minify JS and CSS, optimize images etc.). It should not be Composers' or any package maintainers task to do this optimization for you.